# Some questions about Clemens' paper Cohomology and Obstructions I: Geometry of formal Kuranishi theory

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, deformation-theory

I am reading the paper [Cohomology and Obstructions I: Geometry of formal Kuranishi theory](http://cn.arxiv.org/abs/math/9901084v4) written by Herbert Clemens. I have found this paper hard to follow even though I am familiar with the classical deformaion theory developed by Kodaira-Spencer. In particular, I have the following questions:

1. In the last paragraph of page 11, Clemens write, If for an ideal $\mathfrak{A}\subseteq \mathfrak{m}=\{t_1,\cdots,t_s\}$, we let
   $$\Delta_{\mathfrak{A}}:= Spec\frac{\mathbb{C}[t]}{\mathfrak{A}}\subseteq \Delta.$$
   I should add that $\Delta$ is a polydisc with coordinates $\{t_1,\cdots,t_s\}$. My question is that what is the meaning of the inclusion $Spec\frac{\mathbb{C}[t]}{\mathfrak{A}}\subseteq \Delta$? Is this inclusion in the category of schemes or complex sapces? I have the same question for 
   $$M_{\mathfrak{A}}:=\pi^{-1}(\Delta_{\mathfrak{A}}),$$
   where $\pi: M\to \Delta$ is a deformation of the central fiber $M_0$.
2. In page 18. What is the meaning of the sentence "$M_{\mathfrak{A}}/\Delta_{\mathfrak{A}}$is an infinitesimal deformation of compact Kahler manifolds"? What is the definition of extending a family $M_{\mathfrak{A}}/\Delta_{\mathfrak{A}}$ to a family $M_{\mathfrak{A}'}/\Delta_{\mathfrak{A}'}$ for some ideal $\mathfrak{A}\supseteq \mathfrak{A}'\supseteq \mathfrak{m}\mathfrak{A}$.?

Edit: I find a good interpretation of the notion Spec is given in pp.36 of [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0507286) note by Marco Manetti. See also pp.121 of H. Grauert, T, Peternell and R. Remmert. Several Complex Variables VII,
Sheaf-Theoretical Methods in Complex Analysis, Springer-Verlag Berlin
Heidelberg, 1994.

Answer (score 5):

1. It is an inclusion of analytic spaces — $\Delta $ is not a scheme. If $\mathfrak{A}=(f_1,\ldots ,f_p)$, $\Delta _{\mathfrak{A}}$ is the subspace of $\Delta $ defined by $f_1=\ldots =f_p=0$. I think $\mathfrak{A}\neq 0$ is implicitely assumed, so $\Delta _{\mathfrak{A}}$ is a fattening of the origin. Hence $M _{\mathfrak{A}}$ is what is called an infinitesimal deformation of $M_0$.
2. If $\mathfrak{A}'\subset \mathfrak{A}$, $\Delta _{\mathfrak{A}}$ is a subspace of $\Delta _{\mathfrak{A}'}$, so you look for a family over $\Delta _{\mathfrak{A}'}$ which induces the given family over $\Delta _{\mathfrak{A}}$.

I think your questions would be more appropriate on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @abx You propose to intepret $\Delta _{\mathfrak{A}}$ as the compelx analytic space $(V(\mathfrak{A}), \mathscr{O}_{\Delta}/\mathscr{I})$, where  $V(\mathfrak{A}) $ is the zero set of the ideal $\mathfrak{A}$ and $\mathscr{I}$ is the ideal sheaf of $V(\mathfrak{A}) $. But this has nothing to do with the notation $Spec\frac{\mathbb{C}[t]}{\mathfrak{A}}$. Besides, why the polynomial ring $\mathbb{C}[t]$ appear not the ring of holomorphic functions?

Comment: I have seen three definitions of infinitesimal deformation in the literature:1. a cohomology class in $H^1(M, \Theta)$. 2.a deformation over the dual numbers $k[\epsilon]/\epsilon^2$. 3. a deformation over a zero dimensional compelx analytic space. Now if $M_{\mathfrak{A}}/\Delta_{\mathfrak{A}}$ is a infinitesimal deformation, then the ideal $\mathfrak{A}$ shoud not be arbitrary. Right?

Comment: 1. "nothing to do": they are exactly the same object. 2. For any nonzero ideal $\mathfrak{A}$ the space $\Delta_{\mathfrak{A}}$ is zero-dimensional.